# Are extra fields added with hook_entity_extra_field_info(). not available on product variation pages?

Tags: commerce

Is it generally impossible to render an extra field on product variation pages, because of how the variant fields are injected into product pages?

I added an extra field to the product variations with `hook_entity_extra_field_info()`. and I see it in the "Manage Display" Tab like it would appear on any other entity. But I can't output it. It is simply not available in the theme. If I do a {{ dump() }} in the product variation template it is not listed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this hook only adds metadata to the entity view mode. You have to add the output in a different hook if the view mode has this field configured:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_product_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($display->getComponent('my_extra_field')) {
    $build['my_extra_field'] = [
      '#markup' => 'Extra field content.', 
    ];
  }
}
```

Then it will end up in the `content` variable of your theme.